# Running Ripple emulator in with visual studio cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

I'm not able to run the Sample App in the Ripple (created with new `Multi Device Hybrid App` from Visual Studio 2013). When I run the app, Chrome opens but it stucks on loading page. (I allowed any action when Windows Firewall popped-up).

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Dan

PS: Great job for preview version, Seems much much better than the JBoss Tools Cordova plugin for Eclipse I tried. (horrible)

[image]

Comment: There have been issues similar to what you describe where Chrome launches but does not redirect to Ripple.  Chrome may have become corrupted in some way. Please try re-installing Chrome to see if that addresses the issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem I am getting issues as well with chrome but in my case it given an error or web page not found. It works fine when i run for my windows 8 app but not with ripple

Comment: hey. I didn't find any solution, but I haven't try re installing the browser yet; it indeed seems to be a chrome issue as I have it working fine on a different machine without doing anything special ...

Answer (score 1):

You are already aware of the Windows firewall issue listed in the FAQ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn727288). However, I ran into this issue today--for the first time--when I switched over from my work to my home network.

As a workaround, I resolved the issue by turning off my wireless network connection; so it appears the firewall issue is the root of the cause. I haven't tried the steps in the FAQ. If you're wired, you might try unplugging from the network to verify cause.